# PhpStorm does not load Laravel projects after copying them into new device

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, phpstorm, laravel-8

I just installed latest XAMPP on my laptop and copied and pasted my `htdocs` projects of PC system into this new XAMPP `htdocs`.

Then tried opening them up in PhpStorm, but when I run `php artisan serve` on any project here, I get these errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Failed to load F:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll, The system cannot find the file specified.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Failed to load F:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll, The system cannot find the file specified.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.d
ll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (T
he specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_cur
l.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll
 (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext
\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_
fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.d
ll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (T
he specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\p
hp_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_ge
ttext.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext
\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_
mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_exi
f.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll
 (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php
_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysq
li.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\e
xt\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\ph
p_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php
\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ext\
php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), F:
\xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xamp
p\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\p
hp\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried: F:\xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be found.), F:\xampp\php\ex
t\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot open 'F:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot open 'F:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start standard module in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unable to start standard module in Unknown on line 0
```

The interesting part is that I didn't install XAMPP and drive `F:\`. But as you can see in these error message the messages are coming from `F:\` directory which is the directory of XAMPP on my PC system.

```
Cannot open 'F:\xampp\php\
```

So why am I receiving these errors? How can I properly run my Laravel projects without getting these errors?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys cause my LIFE DEPENDS ON THIS!

Comment: `PHPStorm` is an IDE, not a webserver or PHP processor, though it can pass information off to one. This has more to do with xampp than PHPStorm

Comment: @aynber But I can run commands with CMD at my projects directory

Comment: @user2819411 Check `PHP Interpreter` in PhpStorm then -- maybe it points to the wrong PHP executable etc. So far (based on the errors) it's PHP issue and not PhpStorm. You need to provide more details / be clear about your setup.

Comment: @user2819411 Run `php -v` and see if it will produce any errors. Run your `php artisan serve` in your terminal (not inside PhpStorm) -- does it work there? Perhaps you have copied your PHP config across system as well...

Comment: @LazyOne Yes terminals works fine but phpstorm shows me those errors. How to check php interpreter of phpstorm?

Comment: @user2819411 *"How to check php interpreter of phpstorm?"* Open PhpStorm Settings/Preferences and type `php interpreter` in the search box? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html Right now it looks like you may have more than one PHP in your system and your system terminal uses one and inside PhpStorm it uses another. You better know your system setup and how it works there. Right now I may only suggest restart the whole computer: it often helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a PHP problem and not a IDE problem.

Have you tried enabling the extensions mentioned in the errors in php.ini? and try to install PHP globally, so that you can avoid any issues related to the xampp directory when executing PHP commands.